# ANTLR-based rule engine in java

Tags: validation, antlr, antlr4, rule-engine, fix-protocol

I am writing ANTLRv4 grammar to implement a simple rule engine to parse FIX messages, and specify action to be taken when the rule is violated.

This is where my grammar currently stands:

```
    grammar RuleDefinition;

ruleset: rule+;

rule :  'tag(' INT ')' numberOp (INT | FLOAT| STRING) (ACTION_DIRECTOR action)?;

ID      :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;        // match identifiers
INT     :   [0-9]+;            // match integers
FLOAT   :   '0'..'9'+('.'('0'..'9')*)? ;            // match float
NEWLINE :'\r'? '\n' ;           // return newlines to parser (end-statement signal)
WS     : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;   // toss out whitespace
NUMBER_OP      :   EQ|GR|GE|LS|LE|NE;
numberOp       :   EQ|GR|GE|LS|LE|NE;
EQ      :   '=';
GR: '>';
GE: '>=';
LS: '<';
LE: '<=';
NE: '!=';
ACTION_DIRECTOR : '->';
action: 'WARN' | 'ERROR';
STRING : '"' (' '..'~')* '"';
```

The problem is that the generated code is unable to correctly parse when a rule contains an ACTION_DIRECTOR (->), the error I get is "mismatched input 'ERROR' expecting ACTION"

Parsing is successful for:

```
tag(9)>0
```

Parsing fails for:

```
tag(9)>0 -> ERROR
```

Any pointers on how to correct the above are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this three lines:

```
WARN: 'WARN';
ERROR: 'ERROR';
ACTION: WARN|ERROR;
```

These are lexer rules (upper case start character). The lexer is responsible to split your input into tokens of a determined type. 'ERROR' can only have one token type and ANTLR decides it to be `ERROR` (two rules `ERROR` and `ACTION` match, and `ERROR`is first defined).

To resolve this transform some lexer rules to parser rules (lower case start character):

```
rule :  'tag' '(' INT ')' numberOp (INT | FLOAT| STRING) (ACTION_DIRECTOR action)*;

....

action : WARN | ERROR;
numberOp :   EQ|GR|GE|LS|LE|NE;
stringOp :   EQ|NE;

...
```

Parser rules compose tokens instead of joining them. That means an action can be `WARN` or `ERROR`.

Comment: Hi CoronA, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I cant get this to work. I've changed my grammar as advised, but I get "mismatched input '=' expecting {'=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', '!='}".

Comment: Update your grammar definition and the sample string that makes the parser fail.

Comment: Hi CoronA, I've updated the grammer with your suggestions. The parsing fails with "tag(9)>0" which was parsed successfully earlier.

Comment: numberOp is a replacement for `NUMBER_OP`, you have to remove numberOp.

Comment: works! :) Many thanks for your help, I've accepted the answer.